# Cucumber java - How to handle timeout of any step defifnition

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am using old version of cucumber jvm (not the latest one **5.x**). I am using below way to handle timeout in step definition. But currently it does not fail or stop execution if my step definition execution takes more than 5 seconds.

Any suggestion how to handle timeout for cucumber java?

`@Then(value = "^verify (\\d+) events sent$", timeout = 5000)`

Answer (score 0):

From the [release-notes](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/f6fb4160d4f3298918fd58f36cc256aeb25ed8f9/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#removing-timeout):

> It was possible to provide a timeout to step definitions.
> Unfortunately the semantics are complicated. Cucumbers implementation
> would attempt to interrupt the long running step but would not stop if
> the step was stuck indefinitely.
>
> Additionally Cucumber would not consider a step failed if it did not
> terminate within the given timeout. To remove the confusion and
> complexity we removed timeout from Cucumber.
>
> Consider replacing this functionality with the features provided by
> one of these libraries instead:
>
> - JUnit 5 Assertions.assertTimeout*
> - Awaitility
> - Guava TimeLimiter